# Neural network:same input for training, different weight matrix for the network

Tags: c#, neural-network, backpropagation, accord.net

I have 5 values within a range [INPUTMIN, INPUTMAX] which are the variables of my function and a result of 5 output values whose values are between [OUTPUTMIN, OUTPUTMAX]; Both intervals are predefined and fixed.

I have 100 examples, **which remain unaltered for different training sessions**, that is, for the training set. I use "ResilientBackpropagationLearning" of the Accord.Neuro libraries that manages intelligently the **momentum** (I do not really know how to do it).

What I get is that in 2 different network training I get different network weights matrices!

How is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Have you traineda network twice. You understand that network weights are initialised randomly, right?

Comment: Well this is my problem:I have a set of vector inputs of 5 elements VectorIN and another always 5 vectorOUT elements as output.  
The problem is to find out if there exists between the pairs VectorIN [i] and vectorOUT [i], for i = 1 -> i = 100, or not a function f: R5 -> R5 for which f (Vector [v [1 ]) = VectorOUT [i];
If I exist I would like to train a neural network that approximates the behavior of this function.